# MonoTouch / MonoDevelop Ad Hoc Build Failure But Project Bundle ID and Provisioning Profile Match

Tags: .net, iphone, build, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm running into a really vexing problem with MonoTouch/MonoDevelop.  I'm trying to build an app for Ad Hoc distribution in MonoDevelop for the iPhone.

I've followed these steps:

1. Requested, created, and installed my Distribution certificate on the iOS Provisioning Profile.
2. Registered all of the needed devices.
3. Created the needed App Id (9UKRFP74U9.com.lc.sjd.calc).
4. Created a new provisioning profile for the newly created App Id and downloaded it.
5. Created an "Ad Hoc" configuration in MonoDevelop.
6. Set the Bundle Signing - Identity to my Distribution ID.
7. Set the Bundle Signing - Provisioning profile to the newly created and downloaded Provisioning Profile.
8. Even set the custom entitlements file to a created plist file.

But, and here is the big issue, I am getting a build error when I try to compile in my newly created Ad Hoc build configuration with the following warning:

Error: Project bundle ID '9UKRFP74U9.com.lc.sjd.calc' does not match specified provisioning profile 'D8B55EE9-4CB6-45E9-846A-3C94F8A51907' (SJDCalculator)

But, importantly, when I check the iPhone Configuration Utility, the Profile Identifier and App Identifier are an exact match.

The Build Output only gets to "Detecting signing identity...", then the ------ Done ------- line.

I would really appreciate any help you can offer.  I have been banging my head on this one for a couple days.

Comment: Are you setting the bundle ID to "9UKRFP74U9.com.lc.sjd.calc" or "com.lc.sjd.calc" ?

Comment: You nailed it!  I was setting the bundle ID to "9UKRFP...".  I feel so stupid!  I knew it was one of those things that I just wasn't seeing anymore, something quite simple.

Answer (score 12):

The solution discussed in the above comments was to not set the Bundle ID to:

```
9UKRFP74U9.com.lc.sjd.calc
```

Instead it should be set to:

```
com.lc.sjd.calc
```

Comment: You should also make sure the Developer certificate is the correct one as the provisioning profile is also associated with the developer (i.e. the developer should be a member of the provisioning profile).